# A pgf plot problem

Tags: pgfplots, lengths

I'm new to pgfplot and I have a pgfplot problem.

figure 1 :As you can see the line is going through the number '2'. How can i fix it?
[image]

figure 2: Also can i fix the line length, going through 2, between 0 and intersection point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
           ytick=\empty,
            xtick={2},
            %xticklabels={2},
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},            
              every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},            
            grid = major
            ]
\addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={0:2}] {6-x^2} node[pos=0.6, above]{$f$};

\addplot[name path=G,green,domain={0:2}] {x}node[pos=.4, below]{$g$};

\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=0:2}]
;
\node[coordinate,pin=30:{$A$}] at (axis cs:3.8,3){};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you actually just want a vertical line from the intersection to the x-axis?

Comment: i need intersection to the x-axis sometimes, yes. but I also need from top of the figure to x axis from time to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid lines go from the bottom of the coordinate system to the top, which is why the grid line go across the `2`. There are other ways of drawing these lines though.

To get the coordinate of the intersection between the two plot lines, you can use the features of the `intersections` library from TikZ. This is loaded by the `fillbetween` library, so it is not necessary to load it specifically. Adding

```
name intersections={of=F and G}
```

to the options of a path (e.g. a `\draw`) will create a coordinate called `intersection-1` at the (first) intersection. To draw a line from the intersection to the x-axis, you can add

```
\draw [name intersections={of=F and G}] ({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1) -- (intersection-1);
```

inside the `axis` environment. Here,

```
({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1)
```

means the point that has the same y-coordinate as the origin of the axis, and the same y-coordinate as `intersection-1`.  `axis cs:` means that the following coordinate uses the coordinates of the axis.

To draw a line from the x-axis through the intersection to the top of the axis, you can use

```
\draw ({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1) -- ({rel axis cs:1,1}-|intersection-1);
```

assuming that `intersection-1` has been defined. The first coordinate is as above. For the second I've used the `rel axis cs` coordinate system, which has (0,0) in the bottom left of the axis, and (1,1) in the top right.

Complete code and output:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick={2},
            %xticklabels={2},
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},            
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},            
            ]
\addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={0:2}] {6-x^2} node[pos=0.6, above]{$f$};

\addplot[name path=G,green,domain={0:2}] {x}node[pos=.4, below]{$g$};

\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=0:2}]
;


\draw [name intersections={of=F and G}] ({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1) -- (intersection-1);

\draw [thick,red,dashed] ({axis cs:0,0}-|intersection-1) -- ({rel axis cs:1,1}-|intersection-1);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]